In a [System.Diagnostics.Process] collection, can I determine the most recently active procces?
Usually with get-process, its mainWindowTitle property gives me the most recently active window, that is the window that is highest in the 'Z order' (for the process passed to get-process). So this question rarely rises.
But more and more, I am dealing with applications that spawn a process for each window it has:
 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
     32   106.21     139.10       0.61   16744   1 PureRef
     32    84.71     122.95       0.50   23588   1 PureRef
     32    87.88     121.03       0.53   28076   1 PureRef

I want to get the process objects in the order the PureRef windows are currently in, on the windows Z order, or even have some way of querying this. Looking at all of the properties for get-process, startTime is the only property dealing with date/time.
The reason why I need this, is that often, window titles have in them file paths, so (Get-Process -Name PureRef).MainWindowTitle:
(Get-Process -Name PureRef).MainWindowTitle

Level Design 1 - PureRef - C:\temp\Level Design 1.pur
Car Shelf - PureRef - C:\temp\Car Shelf.pur
Backgrounds_1 - PureRef - C:\temp\Backgrounds_1.pur

and I would like to write simple generic commands such as Get-Pureref, that will return a list of paths in the most recently used windows order, so Get-PureRef so should do:
C:\temp\Level Design 1.pur
C:\temp\Car Shelf.pur
C:\temp\Backgrounds_1.pur

Its critical for me to have this order so that something like (Get-PureRef)[0] | <Do-Something> always means I am operating on the most recent windows file, which is a typical convention on my system already.
I am on PWSH 7.4

Process ids are assigned by numerically in order.  So the lowest id is the first and highest id is the last assigned.

@jdweng - process ids are random as far as I can see, not incrementing - try this 1..5 | % { start-process "notepad.exe" -PassThru } | select-object -expandproperty id for example - I just got 21628 30604 26508 30996 29336, but the OP appears more interested in the Z-Order of apps on the desktop in any case...

@mclayton : Process ID are always assigned in order starting with zero when a machine is started.  The ids may not appear in order if you are listing the ids by the process name.  The OP want to find out which process started last which is the ID with the highest ID.

@jdweng - the script in my previous comment starts 5 x new notepad.exe processes - the output from the script shows the processes are not created with ids in ascending order.

@mclayton : They are just not listed on order.  Windows assigns process ids sequentially and that cannot be changed.  Windows is multi-processing so processes get swapped but any new process assignment is always in order of TIME.

@mclayton some folks don't trust empirical evidence, can't argue with those  you'd be just wasting your time and energy
